# Change push notification sound in code: iOS

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, unusernotificationcenter

I would like to change some parameters of Push Notification without changing payload from backend side.

So the app receives a push notification:

```
{
    "Simulator Target Bundle": "com.test.iphone.driver.test",
    "aps":{
        "alert":"This is Alert.",
        "sound":"default"
    }
}
```

But I need to change sound in code to "custom.mp3" before performing notification.
It should be done in this method: willPresent notification before calling completion handler

```
func userNotificationCenter( _ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
        willPresent notification: UNNotification,
        withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void
      ) {
       completionHandler([.banner, .sound]) 
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: One "ugly" solution is to create a new local notification with all parameters from the remote one, setup custom sound, then don't call completion but call new local notification 0.1 sec after received remote one.